# Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at Port 443 for wordpress

Tags: apache2, openssl, wordpress, aws

I'm facing an error in Wordpress after installing `Let's encrypt certificate` in AWS on Ubuntu 18.04.

[image: Click here see the error message image]

How to fix this issue?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1088196/1665581 The above solution works for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get solution for the issue, need to change in `apache2.conf` file after that it will works,

old code in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

changed in to

```
 <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
```

after that, 
In order for Apache to understand rewrite rules, we first need to activate mod_rewrite. It's already installed, but it's disabled on a default Apache installation. Use the a2enmod command to enable the module:

```
$ sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

This will activate the module or alert you that the module is already enabled. To put these changes into effect, restart Apache.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

it works for me finally.

Answer (score -1):

i hop your 443 port its block

login your aws and check open ports details

more info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html)